# How do I run a jar file with msbuild?

Tags: msbuild

I'm trying to make Visual Studio do my entire build, currently I've got my extra build steps written in nant. But it's not ideal having to run ant separately.

I'm trying to run a jar file named [plovr](http://plovr.com/) as part of my [node](http://nodejs.org/) application, although at the moment publish keeps failing on the line I've added to my build with exit code 1. This is the code I'm trying at the end of my build file within the `<Project></Projet>` tags.

```
<Target Name="Build">
    <Exec Command="java -jar $(Plovr) build $(PlovrConfig)" />
</Target>
```

I've got these properties setup earlier in the file

```
<Plovr>dependencies\plovr.jar</Plovr>
<PlovrConfig>dependencies\plovr-config.js</PlovrConfig>
```

How can I get msbuild to run the plovr.jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put in the full path to java.exe.....the EXEC command should work.

It just does a command line call....at the end of the day.

```
<Target Name="Build">
    <Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe&quot; -jar $(Plovr) build $(PlovrConfig)" />
</Target>
```

Also note the use of `&quot;`   .. to delimit a quote...

You can also put in some Message's to make sure you have what you think you have:

```
<Message Text="Plovr: $(Plovr)"/>
<Message Text="PlovrConfig: $(PlovrConfig)"/>
```